# slidify and include picture on title page

Tags: slidify

because I am new to slidify, maybe doing a mistake
edited : slidify.css

```
 .title-slide {
       background-color: #b4f2f2;
       background-image:url("C:/download/ibm-db2.png");
    }
```

the color is changed as requested - but the image is not displayed
although the file is in correct location
 Directory of C:\download
07/18/2014  08:13 PM            10,315 ibm-db2.png
thanks for all update
best regards, Guy Przytula

Answer (score 0):

Local image works with a relative path from **assets** folder. For example:
bg:url(assets/img/picture.png)

assets folder is inside your slidify project

```
Your slidify project:
|
|--index.Rmd
|--index.html
|--assets
|  |--img
|     |-- picture.png
|
|--libraries
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter where the picture is, but to keep an order you should follow Jorge's advice.

You need to go to this route: and find "slidify.css"

```
\test1\libraries\frameworks\io2012\css
```

Look and change this part:

```
.title-slide {
  background-color: #FFFFFF; /* #EDE0CF; ; #CA9F9D*/
  background-image:url(D:\\test1\\star-bg.png); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;  

  /* background-image:url(http://goo.gl/EpXln); */
}
```

As you see the path to my logo file has "\". This is the path I get when using: `file.choose()`.

If you use RStudio probably you won't see the image loaded. You need to go to the folder where the index.html is and open it on any browser.